# Where is segment table stored ?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, memory-segmentation

In the segmentation scheme, everytime a memory access is made, the MMU would do a translation from  to the actual address by looking up the segment table.

Is the segment table stored inside the TLB or in RAM ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the segment table stored inside the TLB or in RAM ?

This depends on which type of CPU and which mode the CPU is in.

For 80x86, when a segment register is loaded the CPU stores "base address, limit and attributes" for the segment in a hidden part of the segment register.

For real mode, virtual8086 mode and system management mode, when a segment register is loaded the CPU just does "hidden segment base = segment value * 16" and there's no tables in RAM.

For protected mode and long mode, when a segment register is loaded the CPU uses the value being loaded into the segment register as an index into a table in RAM, and (after doing protection checks) loads the "base address, limit and attributes" information from the corresponding table entry into the hidden part of the segment register.

Note that (for protected mode) almost nobody used segmentation because the segment register loads are slow (due to protection checks and table lookups); so CPU manufacturers optimised the CPU for "no segmentation" (e.g. if segment bases are zero, instead of doing "linear address = virtual address + segment base" a modern CPU will just do "linear address = virtual address" and avoid the cost of an unnecessary addition and start cache/memory lookup sooner) and didn't bother optimising segment register loads much either; and then when AMD designed long mode they realised nobody wants segmentation and disabled most of it for 64-bit code (ignoring segment bases for most segment registers to get rid of the extra addition, and ignoring segment limits to get rid of the cost of segment limit checks). However, operating systems that don't use segmentation were using `gs` and `fs` as a hack to get fast access to CPU specific or thread specific data (because, unlike some other CPUs, 80x86 doesn't have register/s that can only be modified by supervisor code that would be more convenient for this purpose); so AMD kept the "linear address = virtual address + segment base" behaviour for these 2 segment registers and added the ability to modify the hidden "base address" part of `gs` and `fs` (via. MSRs and `swapgs`) to make it easier to port operating systems (Windows) to long mode.

In other words, for 80x86 there are 3 different ways to set a segment's information (by calculation, by table lookup, or by MSR).

Also note that for most instructions (excluding things like segment register loads) 80x86 CPU's don't care how a segment's information was set and only use the hidden parts of segment registers. This means that the CPU doesn't have to consult a table every time it fetches code from `cs` and every time it fetches data from memory. It also means that the majority of the CPU doesn't care which mode the CPU is in (e.g. instructions like `mov eax,[ds:address]` only depend on the values in the hidden part of segment registers and don't depend on the CPU mode); which is why there's no benefit to removing obsolete CPU modes (removing support for real mode wouldn't reduce the size or complexity of the CPU).

For other CPUs; most don't support segmentation (and only support paging or nothing), and I'm not familiar with how it works for any that do support it. However I doubt any CPU would do a table lookup every time anything is fetched (it'd be far too slow/expensive to be practical); and I'd expect that for all CPUs that support segmentation, information for "currently in use" segments is stored internally somehow.

Answer (score -2):

The Segment table is the reference whenever you are using the memory . So the table has to be stored permanently for later use , so it is stored in the Physical Address i.e.., the RAM.